# BackButton Focus on title bar UWP

Tags: button, uwp, focus, title, back

I Have built a UWP application with a back button in the title bar.I want to access the back button in title bar using TAB key. Like we could able to access other button control which are inside the application, Seems these button of outside of application control.

Comment: Hi, the `AppViewBackButton` is located on the `TitleBar`. It does not belong to the internal control of the application, but has the corresponding system behavior.

You cannot use the Tab key to navigate here. Tab navigation can only be used inside the app.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion.
If we need to make the focus on to to back button using TAB key then we need to customize the tile bar.
They are various links available for reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar

Comment: This is a viable workaround to your needs, you can write it as an answer and mark it. This will help more people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to make the focus on to to back button using TAB key then we need to customize the tile bar. They are various links available for reference learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar